# Fetching Java variable from JSP into Script tag

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I am writing a JSP and have the Java code written in the `<code>` tags.

I would like to use a Java variable which is inside the `<code>` tag, inside the script tag.

Example:-

```
  <html>
    <head>
    var myJSVar = $(myJavaVariable)//Something like this and this doesn't work
    </head>
    <body>
    <pre>
    <code>
     String myJavaVariable = "Sample String";
    </code>
    .....
```

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java variable in a jsp tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121954/java-variable-in-a-jsp-tag)

Answer (score 2):

First you have to declare ,
    <%
        String myJavaVariable = "Sample String";
    %>

Then in script,
    
        var myJSVar = "<%=myJavaVariable%>";

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to get java variable inside a script. you can set the values in to a HTML element using java after you have done that you can use  `<script>` tag to access the values which is in HTML element

```
    <% String Name="myName"; %>
    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name"  value="<%=Name%>" maxlength="50" />
```

using script tag to get the data in html element.

```
<script>              
    var name = document.getElementById('Name').value;
    <script>
```

`<code>` is not a tag used in HTML to write java code. so you cant do any coding inside a code tag anything you will write in there will be just interpreted on browser in the format of a code.

changed the answer according to your comments.example on getting values as a json and converting them to java objects

```
  String json = "{\"Name\":\"priyamal\",\"Mob\":\"077045\"}";
    ObjectMapper mapperobject = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Object> javaobj = mapperobject.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>() { });
    out.println("MyName:" + javaobj.get("Name") + "Mobile:" + javaobj.get("Mob"));
```

Comment: Actually I have a Json object like jsonPrettyPrintString it will display the json data on browser.  I need a tree structure of ui on browser but it's simply displaying plain json code.

Comment: first of all you should to know how to ask a question properly.you have never mention anything related to getting values from as a json string.
wait i'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to use java variable on jsp

1. `${message}`
2. `<%String myVar="blabla";%>`

Hope this is useful for you.